# How to combine 5 Excel files with the same name but in 5 different folders?

Tags: python, pandas

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import os
d1 = "D:\master concordia\DYD\Ecobee DYD\canada\y\Canada 2015"
d2 = "D:\master concordia\DYD\Ecobee DYD\canada\y\Canada 2016"
d3 = "D:\master concordia\DYD\Ecobee DYD\canada\y\Canada 2017"
d4 = "D:\master concordia\DYD\Ecobee DYD\canada\y\Canada 2018"
d5 = "D:\master concordia\DYD\Ecobee DYD\canada\y\Canada 2019"
output_dir = "D:\master concordia\DYD\Ecobee DYD\canada\y\new"
files_2015= os.listdir(d1)
files_2016= os.listdir(d2)
files_2017= os.listdir(d3)
files_2018= os.listdir(d4)
files_2019= os.listdir(d5)
```

I have 5 folders that contain 800 excel files, the excel files has the same name in each folder, I want to create a loop so I can combine the 5 excel files with the same name into one file. Can someone please help me?

Comment: If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I can't create the loop and I'm new in python so I don't know where to start

Comment: I suggest you start by reading a Python tutorial that includes information on reading files — _not_ by essentially asking for one here. Note that standard Python doesn't understand the Excel file formation, so you probably want to download and install a third-party module that can read and write them.

Comment: @martineau I don't have any problem reading excel files I can do that for multiple excel files, what I can't do is creating a loop that can read 4 files with the same name from 4 different location a combine them

Comment: Then add the code you have to your question and tag your question with which third-party module you're using to read them.

Comment: You can read files in different locations by specifying complete paths to them (it doesn't matter if they have the same file names). i.e. `folder1/thefile.xlsx`, `folder2/thefile.xlsx`, etc.

Comment: @martineau I added the code where i specify each folder path and the list of folder inside, i just want to know how start a loop so I can read and combine the files with the same name

Comment: That's much better and now someone will be a lot more likely to answer your question. Unfortunately, I don't have pandas installed. You might also need to be more specific about what you mean by "combine".

Comment: salam, are the files in a sub foldered (i.e do they lie under `D:\sales\2018\...`) ? you can do this quite easily with Pathlib i'll post an answer in a mo also what's the file name pattern>?

Comment: also do the excel files have multiple sheets ?

Comment: @Datanovice the files in sub folders yes can you tell me how to do it with pathlib and the file name pattern is something like this "ffb034be30cd9b2d19e8f443b6232db74a270d4c" and no there isn't multiple sheets, only one sheet for each file

Comment: @AyaDoma check out the answers, if you're happy please green tick your optimal solution so this can be closed :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't have pandas installed, so while this doesn't answer your entire question, it does show how to iteratively get each corresponding groups of files with the same name from each of the directories, open, and then process them.

Note I shortened the root directory path for testing purposes.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from glob import glob
#import pandas as pd
#from pandas import ExcelWriter
import os

@contextmanager
def multi_file_manager(filenames, mode='r'):
    """ Open multiple files and make sure they all get closed. """
    files = [open(filename, mode) for filename in filenames]
    yield files
    for file in files:
        file.close()

root_dir = "Ecobee DYD"
folder_names = ("Canada 2015", "Canada 2016", "Canada 2017", "Canada 2018", "Canada 2019")
folder_paths = (os.path.join(root_dir, subfolder, "*.xlsx") for subfolder in folder_names)
folder_iters = [iter(sorted(glob(folder_path))) for folder_path in folder_paths]

while True:
    try:
        # Get next group of filenames.
        xl_filenames = [next(folder_iter) for folder_iter in folder_iters]
    except StopIteration:
        break
    with multi_file_manager(xl_filenames) as inp_files:  # Open all in group.
        print('processing files:', ', '.join(['"{}"'.format(f.name) for f in inp_files]))
        # Combine group of open files in inp_files using pandas...

print('done')
```

Sample output:

```
processing files: "Ecobee DYD\Canada 2015\file1.xlsx", "Ecobee DYD\Canada 2016\file1.xlsx", "Ecobee DYD\Canada 2017\file1.xlsx", "Ecobee DYD\Canada 2018\file1.xlsx", "Ecobee DYD\Canada 2019\file1.xlsx"
processing files: "Ecobee DYD\Canada 2015\file2.xlsx", "Ecobee DYD\Canada 2016\file2.xlsx", "Ecobee DYD\Canada 2017\file2.xlsx", "Ecobee DYD\Canada 2018\file2.xlsx", "Ecobee DYD\Canada 2019\file2.xlsx"
processing files: "Ecobee DYD\Canada 2015\file3.xlsx", "Ecobee DYD\Canada 2016\file3.xlsx", "Ecobee DYD\Canada 2017\file3.xlsx", "Ecobee DYD\Canada 2018\file3.xlsx", "Ecobee DYD\Canada 2019\file3.xlsx"
done
```

#### Update

I can't actually test the following because, as I said, I don't have `pandas` installed, however I think it would do what you want. I've put code in for doing the reading, combining, and writing the result using `pandas`, but it's all commented-out.

Also changed it to use `pathlib` to handle the grouping of file from each sub-directory because it's slightly simpler.

The combined files it creates and puts into the `output_folder` are named `filename_combined.xlsx` as a guess because you didn't mention what their names should be in your question.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from glob import glob
from itertools import chain, groupby
##import pandas as pd
##from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pathlib import Path
from pprint import pprint, pformat
from textwrap import indent

root_folder = Path('Ecobee DYD/canada/y')  # Shortened for testing.
subfolders = 'Canada 201[5-9]/*.xlsx'
all_excels = sorted(filepath for filepath in root_folder.glob(subfolders))
output_folder = Path("D:/master concordia/DYD/Ecobee DYD/canada/y/new")

# Create dictionary of unique file names and a list of all the paths to each.
groups = defaultdict(list)
for k, g in groupby(all_excels):
    groups[Path(k.name)].append(next(g))

# Process each group of files.
for filename, xl_filenames in chain(groups.items()):
    print('Combining files:')
    print(indent(pformat(xl_filenames), ' '*4))
##    dfs = [pd.read_excel(xl_filename) for xl_filename in xl_filenames]
##    df = pd.concat(dfs)
    outputfile_path = output_folder / (filename.stem + '_combined' + filename.suffix)
    print('  Result: "{}"'.format(outputfile_path.as_posix()))
##    with ExcelWriter(outputfile_path) as writer:
##        df.to_excel(writer)

print('done')
```

Sample output:

```
Combining files:
    [WindowsPath('Ecobee DYD/canada/y/Canada 2015/file1.xlsx'),
     WindowsPath('Ecobee DYD/canada/y/Canada 2016/file1.xlsx'),
     WindowsPath('Ecobee DYD/canada/y/Canada 2017/file1.xlsx'),
     WindowsPath('Ecobee DYD/canada/y/Canada 2018/file1.xlsx'),
     WindowsPath('Ecobee DYD/canada/y/Canada 2019/file1.xlsx')]
  Result: "D:/master concordia/DYD/Ecobee DYD/canada/y/new/file1_combined.xlsx"
Combining files:
    [WindowsPath('Ecobee DYD/canada/y/Canada 2015/file2.xlsx'),
     WindowsPath('Ecobee DYD/canada/y/Canada 2016/file2.xlsx'),
     WindowsPath('Ecobee DYD/canada/y/Canada 2017/file2.xlsx'),
     WindowsPath('Ecobee DYD/canada/y/Canada 2018/file2.xlsx'),
     WindowsPath('Ecobee DYD/canada/y/Canada 2019/file2.xlsx')]
  Result: "D:/master concordia/DYD/Ecobee DYD/canada/y/new/file2_combined.xlsx"
Combining files:
    [WindowsPath('Ecobee DYD/canada/y/Canada 2015/file3.xlsx'),
     WindowsPath('Ecobee DYD/canada/y/Canada 2016/file3.xlsx'),
     WindowsPath('Ecobee DYD/canada/y/Canada 2017/file3.xlsx'),
     WindowsPath('Ecobee DYD/canada/y/Canada 2018/file3.xlsx'),
     WindowsPath('Ecobee DYD/canada/y/Canada 2019/file3.xlsx')]
  Result: "D:/master concordia/DYD/Ecobee DYD/canada/y/new/file3_combined.xlsx"
done
```

Comment: really like this multi_file_manager will defo be adding that to my own code. Thanks Martineau, you're a true gent.

Comment: @Datanovice: Shalom and thanks for the complement. The use of `pathlib` in your own answer convinced me it could be used to simplify things to some degree, so I added an update to my answer that also uses it. It also makes the `mult_file_manager()` function unnecessary. In addition to that, I borrowed your `pandas` code for reading and combining the Excel files (assuming it's correct since I can test it).

Comment: Shalom eleicum! nice one, knowledge is to be shared, instead of using a mix of the os.module you can entirely reply upon the pathlib instead, you can get the file name without the extension prefix with `file.stem` and the entire file by `file.name` without the path extension.

Comment: @Datanovice: Indeed, using your `pathlib` tips make the use of the `os` module completely unnecessary—so I've updated my update accordingly. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Cannot edit 1 character, please `s/rom context/from context/`

Comment: @gboffi: Thanks—fixed.

Answer (score 0):

using `pathlib` from the python standard library.

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
```

### we can use `rglob` to recursively search a directory tree for all files that match a pattern

```
folder_to_search = 'D:\master concordia\DYD\Ecobee DYD\canada'
pat_ = 'ffb034be30cd9b2d19e8f443b6232db74a270d4c'
all_excels = [f for f in Path(folder_to_search).rglob(f'*{pat_}*.xlsx')]
```

then, we use need to concat them into a single pandas dataframe, remember the shape of the excel files must be the same to get a standard dataframe.

```
dfs = [pd.read_excel(f,sheet_name='Sheet1') for f in all_excels]
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

more about Pathlib here : https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/